# Modelling Redux state in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm looking for a clean way to model Redux state within my React app. Here is one way I could do it which I really dislike:

```
const filmFuncs = {
    getTitles: function () {
        return this.currentTitles.map(function(film) {
            return film.title;
        });
    }
};

const defaultState = {
    'currentTitles': [],
    ...filmFuncs,
};

var reducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_FILMS": {
            return {...state, currentTitles: action.payload};
            break;
        }
    }
    return state;
};

export default reducer;
```

So now I can call, this.props.films.getTitles(); instead of putting logic in my component.

Alternatively, I was thinking I could set up a separate model class and pass the state in, something like this:

```
var filmModel = new FilmModel(this.props.films);
filmModel.getTitles();
```

I'm not really keen on that approach either though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just telling you that the `break` in your reducer is unnecessary. You already `return` at the previous line, so the `break` is unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So now I can call, this.props.films.getTitles(); **instead of putting logic in my component.**

Why exactly are you trying to avoid putting logic in your component?

Such logic is best to be put inside a container/smart component. In your use-case such component would connect to the Redux state, perform *getTitles* selection and pass selected data to a dumb component to render it.

If you really, really want to avoid putting the logic inside a component, you can put it into standalone helper/selector file and then use the selector in your connect. You may use library like Reselect to create flexible selectors.

I suggest reading into article by Dan Abramov on smart vs. dumb components. Link [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Code example:

Selectors file:

```
export const titlesSelector = (state) => state.currentTitles.map(film => film.title)
```

Components file:

```
//Imports
import { titlesSelector } from "./Selectors"

//The smart component

@connect(state => ({
  titles: titlesSelector(state)
}))
export default class SmartComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()

    this.getTitles = this.getTitles.bind(this)
  }

  render (
    return (
      <DumbComponent
        titles={this.props.titles}
      />
    )
  )
}

// The dumb component

const DumbComponent = ({ titles }) => 
<ul>
  {titles.map(title => <li>{title}</li>}
</ul>
```

Comment: *"Why exactly are you trying to avoid putting logic in your component?"* -- I'd like to throw in my opinion regarding _testability_ here: I always try to keep my components as slim as possible, because there is no way I'm going to jump into a maintenance hell by unit testing the output of (all/most) react components. Now, if all your app logic is in stores/utility classes, it's infinitely more feasible to perform unit testing by ensuring store(s) perform the correct state change in response to a given action.

Comment: What if there is logic that you want to reuse, but not necessarily the component itself?

Take the example of returning an array of titles like in my question. Perhaps I want to have two components that display a list of titles. One which creates a set of clickable links for each title, another which lists each title wrapped in a styled div. Ideally I would like to share the getTitles() logic between each component.

Comment: Then export the function from separate file and include it whenever you need it. As I mentioned above. Anyway, I understand. I should have probably pointed out that the reducer is not the right place to store selectors (moreover, putting it directly inside state is crazy) in the first place.

Comment: I just refined the example so it suit your use-case more. Extracted the selector from the component. The rest of logic stands the same.

Comment: @jankoritak Thanks, I agree that's probably the best way to go about what I'm after